# How to draw two parallel strips in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, cgcontext

I need to customize the cells of a table creating two transparent strips, one in correspondence of the upper edge of UITableViewCell, and other in correspondence of the lower edge. These strips should be transparent to see the color of the view below (light yellow).
I created a subclass of UITableViewCell and I built the method LayoutSubviews() to draw the strips, it is wrong? I get this errors:

```
   <Error>: CGContextBeginPath: invalid context 0x0
   <Error>: CGContextMoveToPoint: invalid context 0x0
   <Error>: CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0
   <Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0
   <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
   <Error>: CGContextMoveToPoint: invalid context 0x0
   <Error>: CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0
   <Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0
   <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
```

This is the code in CustomCell.m:

```
 -(void) layoutSubviews{
   [super layoutSubviews];


   CGContextRef ctxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGContextBeginPath(ctxt);
   CGContextMoveToPoint(ctxt, self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctxt, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.origin.y);
   CGContextSetLineWidth(ctxt, 5);
   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctxt, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor); 

   CGContextMoveToPoint(ctxt, self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.size.height);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctxt, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
   CGContextSetLineWidth(ctxt, 5);
   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctxt, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
   CGContextStrokePath(ctxt);


}
```

Comment: Do u have any images for your cell background?? if you have then,add a transparent one pixel on top and bottom of your cell image.. And set tableview background view to nil and set clearcolor for the background of your tableView.

Comment: I set the background of tableView of clearColor but the strips not are  transparent but black. What I do wrong?

Comment: did you set [tableView setBackgroundView:nil]?? this also

Comment: Yes, I setBackgroundView but the strips are black and not transparent

Comment: can you send me your project??i will try for myself

Comment: Thanks for help, I managed to solve the problem, I removed the strips and I created a white rectangle smaller than the cell of contentView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`layoutSubviews` is the wrong method to draw something. You don't have a drawing context there. Move your code to `drawRect:`:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect: rect];


   CGContextRef ctxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGContextBeginPath(ctxt);
   CGContextMoveToPoint(ctxt, self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctxt, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.origin.y);
   CGContextSetLineWidth(ctxt, 5);
   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctxt, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor); 

   CGContextMoveToPoint(ctxt, self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.size.height);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctxt, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
   CGContextSetLineWidth(ctxt, 5);
   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctxt, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
   CGContextStrokePath(ctxt);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0];
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);

  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);     //CGContextSetRGBFillColor doesn't work either
  CGContextBeginPath(context);
  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100.0, 60.0);
  CGRect rectangle = {100.0, 60.0, 120.0, 120.0};
  CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);

  CGContextStrokePath(context);
  CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation for this?